# Cocoapod - Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I recently uploaded a new cocoapod of mine, and I was trying to test it. But when I opened up .xcworkspace and ran it...I got an error:

```
".../APMultiMenu.bundle" failed: No such file or directory (2)
done

sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 23
```

Also I noticed in my Products folder (under Pods), it says there is a file APMultiMenu.bundle, but it is red so it is missing. But what I dont understand is why the .bundle file is even there, because it should not be there? Can someone help

Comment: Solved it by upgrading Cocoapods to 0.36.0.rc.1

Comment: Solved it for me as well.

Comment: @Aadesh, has this been resolved for you as well by updating Cocoapods?